# What do you do when your question might reveal commercially sensitive information?

Tags: discussion

[Why am I getting "String or Binary Data would be Truncated Error" when there's no INSERT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25813425/14250)

See the comments for some not unjustified complaints that I've donned a cloak of secrecy and am making it hard to solve the problem.

Obviously, you really need the table to work out the issue, and a data sample couldn't hurt. The problem is that this is the kind of issue where, because there's only a set number of (sane) ways to solve any problem, exposing the table structure *could* reveal the nature of the problem being worked on. (Aaron's comment that "it's not going to be something no-one's ever thought of", is exactly correct but missing the point)

What a company is currently working on is often marked commercially sensitive information and you can be sued for breaking confidentiality. Or, if it's governmental, arrested. Yes, it's low probability, but the consequences are pretty high if someone does get the wrong end of the stick, far higher than I'd personally want to risk over a database bug.

What's worse is, because this turned out to be an execution plan bug, giving anything other than the literal data is not replicating enough of the environment to be sure that they'll even be able to replicate the bug.

How do you handle the issue of confidentiality when dealing with data structures, while still giving enough information to get useful answers and not be grumbled at in the comments?

Comment: Providing that it would be possible to create one, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would get around most if not all of those issues.

Comment: Programmers that work under the terms of a strict NDA should *never* ask for help on a public Q+A site.  Not even an obfuscated question.  NDAs are always strict about that, it violates the contract.  They need to find paid help, always available and simply the cost of business.

Comment: Bit confused by the downvotes. I felt this question seemed reasonable to ask, even if the answer is "don't ask those kind of questions"

Comment: @JonK: If you check the linked question, an MCVE was really difficult to come up with that didn't cause me concerns about commercial sensitivity or cause the execution plan to change and the bug to "vanish". If I'd understood enough about what was relevant to compose the MCVE, I wouldn't have needed to ask the question. I get that this is a pain, but frankly, I used to be able to come to this site for help with areas I didn't fully understand, and I felt like I made best effort to come up with an MCVE that still replicated the problem, and flesh it out in the comments.

Comment: @HansPassant Good advice, thanks.

Comment: Regarding your confusion about the downvotes on this question: don't worry about them too much. Here on meta, downvotes are usually used more to express agreement or disagreement with a post, rather than as a way to indicate a good or bad quality post, as is the case on the main site. I agree that your question is a reasonable one to ask, and I think the downvotes are peoples' way of saying, "don't use SO if you can't thoroughly explain the problem."

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @SamIam Doesn't work with SQL, because the Execution Plan can change for the same code. I literally got the bug above appearing and disappearing for the *exact* same code as I tried to debug it, as the underlying framework changed the way it derived the execution plan.

Answer (score 9):

As with any problem you're having you should be able to convert the actual problem into a small sample program that demonstrates the problem. This program should use non-sensitive data.

So, most of the time you'll either have a question that can be safely asked or possibly even a solution before you even ask the question. There have been innumerable times where I've found the solution to a problem this way.

Obviously there might be occasions when you can't reproduce the problem with non-sensitive data, but I would have thought that these would be the cases where you can find out what the problem is without posting a question on Stack Overflow.

If you do post sensitive data all we can to is edit it out of the post and ask the team to expunge the previous revisions. This means it's available to no one.

Comment: The problem in this case was that, due to the fact that the problem was appearing erratically (as the SQL execution plan changed with data and when changing parts of the query not directly related to the core fault), creating an MCVE is really difficult to do, because the chances are much higher that you're going to remove the bug without realising it.