# How to immediately remove questions from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

This is an emergency. There are some questions that I would like people to help me with.

I posted questions that contain information from a client and they want me to remove it now, but they have upvoted answers, so I can't. Someone please help me, how can I get it removed?

Comment: If you have sensitive information that you don't want people to see, it's probably better to not make a public post that is specifically drawing attention to said private information, and instead contact SE privately.

Comment: You can also use a flag -> custom reason

Comment: Are you talking about another account of yours? I only see 3 questions: 1 without answers, 1 with a 0 scored answer, 1 closed with no answers.

Comment: Yes I use another user to ask this question.

Comment: How to make it private post , Can you help me where to do it?

Comment: Is actually necessary to delete them? Can't you just remove the important bits?

Comment: What's your concern here? Like @Braiam says - can't you just remove bits that you may feel are sensitive for some reason?

Comment: I edited and removed information but there are some answers that copy my code , I cannot edit the answers .

Comment: Is there anyone who has enough reputation to close my question, please help me, I sent email to stackexchange but I have not receive response . I will repay anyone who help me. Please help.

Comment: Why can't you edit the answers? You could update them with the same anonymised example you're presumably using in the revised question.

Comment: @user2956672 how?  I could not VTC your question because you have not posted any way to access it!  By your own statement: 'I use another user to ask this question'.   That's assuming that any user would want to take the chance of getting embroiled in any pending legal difficulties that you might have precipitated, (which I doubt - you are now radioactive and emitting lawyer-particles: nobody will come near you).

Comment: I assume that you 'client' is a nice, normal business relationship with yourself, and handles such disputes with legal action?  You seem to be driven by extreme panic; you published incriminating details of a drug lord or something?  If so, I assume your posts will suddenly stop soon and your account/s become dormant.

Comment: See also [What do you do when your question might reveal commercially sensitive information?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271378)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless you are a copyright holder. In this case you can request a DMCA take-down.

From Meta.SE FAQ question [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/310998):

> ## If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?
>
> The standard policy for moderators is to decline such flags. The
> reasoning is as follows:
>
> - if you can delete your question (because it has no answers, or the only answer has no upvotes), then you should do it. It does not
>   require moderator intervention.
> - if you cannot delete your question, then there must be upvoted, or multiple answers. Deleting the question also deletes the answers.
>   Deleting the answers undoes the hard work other people have put in to
>   answer your question, and reverses the reputation they have earned
>   too. This is not fair to the answerers of your question.
>
> If you posted a question that you regret posting because:
>
> - it is a school assignment and you have now violated your school's "code of conduct"
> - it is embarrassing because it is a silly question
>
> then deleting the question is not a solution because users with 10K
> (2K on beta sites) reputation can see it still anyway. It is also
> [clear in the terms of service (section 3)](https://stackexchange.com/legal) that:
>
> > You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange
> > under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. You
> > grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license
> > to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create
> > derivative works and store such Subscriber Content ...
>
> Moderators will not delete your question for the above reasons.
>
> *What if I posted my employer's copyrighted code, or there is a copyright violation in my question, and for legal reasons it has to be
> removed?*
>
> Stack Exchange implements a take-down process in accordance with the
> DMCA. If you are a copyright holder, and someone (an employee?) has
> posted content which contravenes your copyright, then you can file a
> copyright take-down and the content will be removed. The process for
> this is [described in section 15 of the terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal).
>
> Flagging your question for moderator attention is not the right
> process to follow.

Comment: How to request to DMCA to take down , please help me, Thanks.

Comment: @user2956672 Read [section 15 of the Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal#15CopyrightPolicy).

Comment: This is probably the right approach (though moderator flagging is not wrong IMO.  Surely moderators have discretion to "do the right thing" whjen the circumstances clearly require it.).  But a legal quibble.  Can you file a (legal) DCMA takedown for content whose copyright you don't own; i.e. your >customer's< info?  Also, does copyright actually apply?  (Is it a creative expression? Is it beyond the "de minimis" threshold: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_minimis ?)

Comment: IANAL I suspect that the OP would need authorization to act as an agent for the client in this matter.

Answer (score -5):

As Gothdo said, you cannot delete the posts. Welcome to the Internet, that's just how it works.

That being said, if the posts contain sensitive information, you could just edit the questions and answers to have placeholder data instead.

If your account is <2k, it might be hard to get the edits on the answers approved, but you could just ping the authors and request very nicely that they update their answers.

It's far less likely for anyone to be paging through the edit history, anyway.

---

In the future you need to be more careful about what you are posting. When you have a contract with your client that forbids you from sharing certain things, you must respect that.

Comment: Also, I would have thought it was **unwise** for a low rep user to be using StackOverflow as a customer support channel.  For a start, a low rep user probably doesn't know enough about StackOverflow to use it properly for this use-case.  (And this Q is a clear illustration of this point.)

Comment: @StephenC What do you mean by "customer support channel"? Is there something about the questions I don't know about?

Comment: Ermm ... maybe I got this wrong, but I was interpreting this as a you were responding to your customer's questions on StackOverflow.  Some folks do use StackOverflow as the way that they provide their dev customer / dev user support.

Comment: @StephenC I took it to mean that OP was a freelancer. Or something like that.

Comment: `if the posts contain sensitive information, you could just edit the questions and answers to remove it` If these "sensitive information" are not relevant to the question and answers, they can be edited out, but it's definitely inappropriate to for example remove all code from posts.

Comment: @Gothdo I didn't mean remove the code. I've clarified that I meant replace the data with placeholder data.